# How can i distinguish cue from other lines using opencv

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I am using this code

```
        Mat gray = new Mat(720, 1280, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
        CvInvoke.CvtColor(img, gray, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
        Mat canny = new Mat(720, 1280, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
        CvInvoke.Canny(gray, canny, 50, 200, 3, false);
        Mat bgr = new Mat(720, 1280, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
        CvInvoke.CvtColor(canny, bgr, ColorConversion.Gray2Bgr);

        LineSegment2D[] lines = CvInvoke.HoughLinesP(canny, 1, Math.PI / 180, 50, 100, 10);

        foreach (LineSegment2D item in lines)
        {
            CvInvoke.Line(img, item.P1, item.P2, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
            outputFile.WriteLine(t);
        }
```

And I get this result

[image]

Original image:

[image]

This is code using emgucv. This is an opencv wrapper for .net, so everything that works in opencv works here. you can leave the solution in any other language or just suggest what can I do to distinguish the cue from other lines? Thanks!

Comment: You can filter the green board first and look for the largest contour from the edge map

Comment: I have to work with coordinates.  I cant filter the background

Comment: You may have to use cv2.fitLine.